# Can I use startActivityForResult multiple times?

Tags: android, android-activity

Can I use startActivityForResult multiple times??

I have 5 activites A,B,C,D,E

```
A->B->C--STARTACTIVITYFORRESULT->D---STARTACTIVITYFORRESULT--->D---SETRESULT-->D
--STARTACTIVITY-->E ---SETRESULT-->C
```

When i Call setresult from E it takes me back to D rather than C. What should i do to make it redirect to ActivityC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of `startActivityForResult` as a `Stack.push`

***example***

1. You have activity ***A*** running
2. You *startActivityForResult* activity ***B***
3. In activity ***B*** you *startActivityForResult* activity ***C***
4. In activity ***C*** you *startActivityForResult* activity ***D***

At this point, in the stack: you have ***A***-***B***-***C***-***D***

If ***D*** finishes, ***D*** is `popped` and you return to ***C***.

When ***C*** finishes, ***C*** is `popped` and you return to ***B***

Finally When ***B*** finishes, ***B*** is `popped` and you return to ***A***

Comment: I cannot pop D as i want the user to be able to go back to it by pressing back button. And secondly want to go to C from E(my example)

Comment: please ask this in a separate question. A user looking for an answer later in the future may get lost and miss valuable information. Cheers.